# What function could map all negative integers to between 0 and 1 and keep all positive integers the same?

Tags: functions

I have an input that can be any integer between -infinity and +infinity.
I would like to find a function that maps all positive integers to themselves (1->1, 2->2 etc) but maps all negative integers to the area between 0 and 1 linearly.

Is this possible? If yes, how would such a function be defined?

Comment: What do you mean "maps all negative integers to the area between $0$ and $1$ linearly"?

Comment: What is the definition of '-infinity' with regards to your input? Do I map $10^{10000}$ to $1$? $10000^{10000000}$ to $1$? What about $2^{2^{2^{\cdots}}}$?

Comment: The smaller the number is the closer it is to 0, the bigger the number is, the closer it is to 1, so -1 would be 0.99999 (but can’t be infinitely many 9’s because that would equal 1) if this is impossible, then maybe it is possible if we don’t consider all negative integers but only up to some value, like -10 000

Comment: Ignoring "linearly"... how about $f(n) = \begin{cases}n&\text{if }n\geq 1\\2^n&\text{if }n\leq 0\end{cases}$?  so you have  $\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline\dots&f(-3)&f(-2)&f(-1)&f(0)&f(1)&f(2)&\dots\\\hline \dots&\frac{1}{8}&\frac{1}{4}&\frac{1}{2}&1&1&2&\dots\\\hline\end{array}$

Comment: If by "linearly", you mean that the distance from $f(-1)$ to $f(-2)$ is the same as the distance from $f(-2)$ to $f(-3)$ and is the same as the distance from $f(n)$ to $f(n-1)$ for all negative integers $n$... that is clearly impossible.

Comment: Okay, I see now how that would be impossible, and your solution is good if we throw the linearity out, and if the range is finite (like -1 to -100) I guess n/-100 could work.

Comment: @JMoravitz it is, unless said distance is $0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, taking a *linear* function, absuing notation one would have that $f(x)=mx+c$ with $f(-\infty)=0$ and $f(0)=1$ arrives at $f(x)=\frac{x}{\infty}+1$ which is simply $1$ everywhere. We can see from here that for each $j\in[0,1]$, the function $$f(x)=\begin{cases}  j & x\leq j \\ x & x\geq j\end{cases}$$ meets the criteria.

Comment: Thank you, while not the answer I was hoping for this i correct and I will mark it as such, I figured out that if I can restrict the range then n/-range for all negative n could work.